# Can not see external IP even though application is accessible from outside

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I created a `Kubernetes` cluster for my `Play` application using the following two `yaml` files couple of days back

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: appname
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: appname
...
```

and

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: appname-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: appname
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

At that time, I got an `external IP` and I can access the application using the external IP.

Today, I ran the following two commands on `GCP` console but I am surprised that I can't see the external IP!

```
gcloud container clusters list
NAME            LOCATION        MASTER_VERSION    MASTER_IP       MACHINE_TYPE  NODE_VERSION      NUM_NODES  STATUS
appname  europe-west2-a  1.16.15-gke.4901  35.Xxx.yyy.zzz  e2-medium     1.16.15-gke.4901  2          RUNNING
$  kubectl get svc

NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.92.0.1    **<none>**        443/TCP   2d23h
```

I also tried getting names of all services but I note that the `appname-service` is not listed!

```
kubectl get services --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
default       kubernetes             ClusterIP   10.92.0.1    <none>        443/TCP         2d23h
kube-system   default-http-backend   NodePort    10.92.6.97   <none>        80:31901/TCP    2d23h
kube-system   kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.92.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   2d23h
kube-system   metrics-server         ClusterIP   10.92.9.35   <none>        443/TCP         2d23h
```

Am I doing something wrong to check the external IP? Am I in incorrect namespace or something?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue was I was looking in the wrong project and cluster. I had (by mistake) created service in wrong cluster. I debugged it by selecting organisation at top level (under which different clusters are created) and then I checked in each cluster. I found the service in wrong cluster!